# JAX-WS null arguments

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I've made a WS server from a WSDL definition (Contract first approach).
I've generated the Java artifacts with wsimport and tested the service. 
Now I've got a problem. Some (not all) arguments of an operation requests are unmarshalled as null!
The web service is SOAP based. The wsdl follow the document-literal convention.
So, this is the schema imported by AbstractFDSInfo.wsdl:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/FDSControl"
        xmlns:com="http://www.example.com/FDSCommon"
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/FDSControl" 
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <import namespace="http://www.example.com/FDSCommon" schemaLocation="FDSCommon.xsd"/>

  <complexType name="PassengerList">
    <sequence>
      <element ref="com:Passenger" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="FlightInstanceStatusList">
    <sequence>
      <element type="com:flightInstanceStatus" name="Status" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <!-- other operation types here -->

  <element name="setPassengerBoarded">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element ref="com:FlightInstanceId"/>
        <element type="string" name="Passenger"/>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
  <element name="setPassengerBoardedResponse">
    <complexType/>
  </element>
  <element name="passengerBoardingException">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
          <element type="token" name="Reason"/>
          <element type="string" name="Detail"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>

  <!-- Other operation types here --->
```

And here is the FDSControlAbstract.wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="FDSControlAbstract"  
             xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/FDSControl.wsdl"
             xmlns:con="http://www.example.com/FDSControl"
             xmlns:com="http://www.example.com/FDSCommon"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"  
             targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/FDSControl.wsdl">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.com/FDSCommon" schemaLocation="FDSCommon.xsd"/>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.com/FDSControl" schemaLocation="FDSControl.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>

  <message name="setPassengerBoardedRequest">
    <part element="con:setPassengerBoarded" name="Params"/>
  </message>
  <message name="setPassengerBoardedResponse">
    <part element="con:setPassengerBoardedResponse" name="Params"/>
  </message>
  <message name="passengerBoardingException">
    <part element="con:passengerBoardingException" name="Params"/>
  </message>

  <!-- other messages here -->

  <portType name="FDSBoardingPortType">

    <!-- other operations here -->

    <operation name="setPassengerBoarded">
      <documentation>
        Sets a passenger as boarded. If the passenger is already boarded, 
        or the flight instance is not in the boarding status, an exception
        is returned.
      </documentation>
      <input message="tns:setPassengerBoardedRequest"/>
      <output message="tns:setPassengerBoardedResponse"/>
      <fault message="tns:flightInstanceNotFoundException"
             name="flightInstanceNotFoundException"/>
      <fault message="tns:passengerBoardingException"
             name="passengerBoardingException"/>
      <fault message="tns:flightStatusException"
             name="flightStatusException"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>

 <!-- other port types here -->

</definitions>
```

Here is the FDSControl.wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="FDSControl"  
             xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/FDSControl.wsdl"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"  
             targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/FDSControl.wsdl"
             elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <import namespace="http://www.example.com/FDSControl.wsdl" location="FDSControlAbstract.wsdl"/>

  <!-- other bindings here-->

  <binding name="FDSBoardingSOAP" type="tns:FDSBoardingPortType">

    <!-- other operations here -->

    <operation name="setPassengerBoarded">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.example.com/FDSControl/setPassengerBoarded"/>
      <input> <soap:body use="literal"/> </input>
      <output> <soap:body use="literal"/> </output>
      <fault name="flightInstanceNotFoundException">
        <soap:fault name="flightInstanceNotFoundException" use="literal"/>
      </fault>
      <fault name="passengerBoardingException">
        <soap:fault name="passengerBoardingException" use="literal"/>
      </fault>
      <fault name="flightStatusException">
        <soap:fault name="flightStatusException" use="literal"/>
      </fault>
    </operation> 
  </binding>

  <service name="FDSBoardingSOAPService">
    <port name="FDSBoardingPortType" binding="tns:FDSBoardingSOAP">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:7070/fdscontrol"/>
    </port>
  </service>

</definitions>
```

Now here is the definition of the java class implementing the web service:

```
@WebService(name="FDSBoarding",
        endpointInterface="it.polito.dp2.FDS.lab4.server.gen.FDSBoardingPortType",
        wsdlLocation="META-INF/FDSControl.wsdl",
        portName="FDSBoardingPortType",
        serviceName="FDSBoardingSOAPService",
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/FDSControl.wsdl")
})
public class FDSControlImpl implements FDSBoardingPortType {
    private FlightManager manager;

    public FDSControlImpl(FlightManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    //other methods here

    @Override
    public SetPassengerBoardedResponse setPassengerBoarded(SetPassengerBoarded params)
    throws FlightInstanceNotFoundException_Exception, FlightStatusException_Exception, PassengerBoardingException_Exception {
        return manager.setPassengerBoarded(params);
    }

}
```

You can see I kept the parameters wrapped in a single class.
Now the problem is that, whenever I send a request for setPassengerBoarded(), the server returns null as params.getPassenger()
Is there something wrong with my structure/definitions?

Comment: I want to clarify that `params.getFlightInstanceId()` returns the right values instead.

Comment: Have you tried to sniff the request? If so, may you publish an example of it in your question? Thanks.

Comment: Yes:
`<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:setPassengerBoarded xmlns="http://www.example.com/FDSCommon" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/FDSControl"><FlightInstanceId flightNumber="HY903" date="2010-02-15+01:00"/><ns2:Passenger>Marta Chemin</ns2:Passenger><ns2:test>ab123</ns2:test></ns2:setPassengerBoarded></S:Body></S:Envelope>`

As you can see, the value is there

Comment: You can see I added a "test" element. I tryed with strings and numbers and always get null for them. May ti be a namespace issue? The values that arrive as null are in the http://www.example.com/FDSControl

Comment: I don't think that it is a namespace related issue (in this case it is likely that you will have compilation problems), but actually I do not know which the reason may be... sorry

Comment: If I wrap that string into a complex type, the server can read it... this is odd, complex type are being unmarshalled but not simple ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was compiling two different WSDLs to the same package. I split the generated code in two packages and the problem disappeared, even though now I have duplicate classes and thus I need to convert back and forth between the these...

Answer (score 0):

I do not have commenting privileges. I would suggest that first test the web service through SOAP UI. 
You would then be sure whether the service is working as you expect or some parameters need to change.
If your test is successful then try to set the same parameters in the proxy.